# Have you ever used KMP or BM algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I know KMP (Knuth–Morris–Pratt) and BM (Boyers-Moore) algorithms are all good string search operation algorithms.
I also know that BM is 3-5 times quicker than KMP.

In your experience of programming for industry software, have you ever used BM or KMP algorithms?
Does the algorithm really matter here?

Comment: I know what KMP stands for but not BM. Would you mind writing down what each of them stands for, in case others don't know?

Comment: @Mehrdad: BM is probably Boyer-Moore.

Comment: yes. BM is boyer-moore. if you search "BM algorithm" on google. you can find it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd care, but I've used Sunday's variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool in real software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look at for example Java's `String.indexOf` function it seems that they use the brute force method for string matching.
You may wonder why that is.

The reason is that some query preprocessing is performed in these algorithms and that may be costly (especially for BM if you use both arrays). Therefore the strings you search in must be of a large size before KMP and BM can beat the brute force method.

There is always a trade off when using different algorithms and when dealing with large strings you may consider indexing of the text instead of the query as well (e.g. suffix trees). This may even be useful when you deal with new texts each time.

In my opinion these algorithms are rather academical and only useful under special circumstances.

Comment: Interestingly the gcc `strstr()` implementation (equivalent to `String.indexOf()`) uses a very cool algorithm that needs only linear time and, unlike BM and KMP, *constant space*.  That basically removes any reason to use the naive O(n^2) method in a library function, since the only cases when it will be faster are on extremely short strings where both algorithms are already very (i.e. sufficiently) fast.  (Got this from MAK's answer.)

Comment: Actually, the *real* indexOf method for `String` isn't usually the one you see in the JDK source, but rather the intrinsic version inserted by the JDK, at least in Sun's hotspot in Java 6 and 7.

That version, in fact, does use a simplified variant of BM.  It works only in the case that the character examined is not in the string at all, in which case it usually (see note) skips N characters, where N is the length of the search string. Note: The *usually* comes in because the algorithm uses a 32-entry hash table to determine if a character appears in the string, so collisions are possible.

Comment: Interesting since in the `iptables` the only choices you have are BM and KMP...

Answer (score 3):

glibc's `strstr` function is linear. It uses a [Two-Way Algorithm](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/str-two-way.h;h=87ed8a03668ce113db7d364dba3e96d69b516de9;hb=HEAD), which I think is a variant of Boyer-Moore. So, I guess that makes anyone using `strstr` in gcc is actually using a fast string search algorithm in the real world.

As for the question of whether a fast algorithm matters, IMHO it matters only if the size of the data is large enough. A lot of the explicit string operations we do is on very small strings (say less than 500 characters). That is not to say we don't do heavy string operations (e.g. full text search on a database), but in that case we generally let the database or a library do the heavy lifting for us. The database or library uses fast string search algorithms - so I wouldn't say they do not matter, only that its use is not visible to us directly.

Comment: Wow!  Linear-time and constant-space, it ticks all the boxes!  Wonder why I haven't heard of this algorithm before.  Have to say I couldn't follow the explanation at http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node26.html#SECTION00260, so I downloaded Crochemore & Perrin's 1991 paper but found it is 25 ominous pages -- over my "casual read" threshold.  :/  One day...

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Too hard to follow for me too. I guess its not as popular as KMP or Rabin Karp for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented once KMP on hardware. If the hardware is an FPGA you can use the reconfigureability to have a self-modifying circuit. This circuit gets the search string. Than make the necessary precommuting in hardware and reconfigures itself to the logic that actually makes the KMP. But here also it is necessary that you have to crawl big amount of data to get a speed up, but there are cases were it is so (e.g. DNA matching).